# How to use V8's built in functions

Tags: c++, v8, javascript-engine

I'm new in both javascript and V8. According to Google's Embedder's Guide, I saw something in the [context section](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html#contexts) talking about built-in utility javascript functions. And I also found some .js files(e.g. math.js) in the downloaded source code, so I tried to write a simple program to call functions in these files, but I failed.

1. Does a context created by `Persistent<Context> context = Context::New()` have any built-in js functions? How can I access them?
2. Is there a way to first import existing js files as a library(something like src="xxx" type="text/javascript" in HTML page) and then run my own execute script?
3. Can I call google maps api through the embedded V8 library in app? How?

Answer (score 1):

`3.` Google Maps needs a full browser DOM (or at least XMLHttpRequest I guess), you can't use it from just a Javascript library.

Comment: Many thanks. I can see the DOM(e.g. XMLHttpRequest)is a browser's built-in object that javascript could use to behave something, so it seems apparently the only way is to import a browser's library?

Answer (score 0):

I think v8 gives you the Math.* functions for free.

You need to implement everything else yourself though, like loading other javascript files. [shell.cc](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/samples/shell.cc) has some of the functions you might be looking for.

As for the maps API, I believe you would need a full blown rendering engine/javascript engine combo for that. You might be better off taking a look at [Webkit](http://webkit.org/) or something that you can use to embed Webkit for what you're looking to do, I can't really say.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example the --allow_natives_syntax or --expose_natives_as option.
Here are examples with MathLog picked at random in src/math.js:

First compile a shell with

```
$ scons d8 -j8
```

Then use --expose_natives_as:

```
$ ./d8 --expose_natives_as nat
V8 version 3.12.7 (candidate) [console: dumb]
d8> nat.MathLog(100)
4.605170185988092
```

or use --allow_natives_syntax with the '%' prefix:

```
$ ./d8 --allow_natives_syntax
V8 version 3.12.7 (candidate) [console: dumb]
d8> %MathLog(100)
4.605170185988092
```